# How can I modify a photo's date on Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I have just viewed my Google Photos account and already have a couple of pictures in my account – it seem to have fetched it from Google+, Picasa or whatsoever. Now I have a bunch of pictures that always appear on top of all the other photos because they – erroneously – are dated in 2075.

Is there a way to modify the date online?

## Update

First of all, in Picasa, instead of being dated 2075, photos and albums are dated 1970. And following [MaryC.fromNZ's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78810/35763) does not wholisticly help: I can redate the albums, but not the photos themselves. And on Google Photos, the default view are the pictures, not the albums, which is still very annoying.

Any other hints? I want to avoid having to download, delete, redate and reupdate all misdated photos.

## Update 2

[See my answer here.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78841/35763)

Comment: I have the same problem, but in the opposite direction. I have a bunch of photos from last year that say they're from 1968.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably recently added by Google, it's now possible to edit the date of photos on photos.google.com itself. Simply open a photo, click on the 'i' information icon and there it is; an editable date.

Comment: Did anyone find a trick to edit the date of multiple photos?

Answer (score 5):

I managed it by navigating (on Picasa photo view) `Actions` > `Edit on Google+` > `Photo details` and click on the date link:

[image]

Richard Williams points out in his comment below:

> The "Edit in Google+" doesn't appear when viewing a video - however if you just open the video in Google+ you can still change the date as in this answer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that worked:   at one stage Actions > Edit in Google+  wasn't working from Picasa Web Albums.   But if it is working now, that's an improvemement.

Comment: Re the date showing as 1970 in PWA - I'm pretty sure that Blogger's "beginning of time" is 1970, so it may have been that these photos didn't have any date stored with them at all, and the 2075 date is Google Photos default value.

Comment: The "Edit in Google+" doesn't appear when viewing a video - however if you just open the video in Google+ you can still change the date as in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, as of July 1, 2015, google photo does not allow you to change the properties of you photo except for the description. I know the original Questioner does not want to download or re upload, but I have found this to be the easiest and fastest way to work around this issue using Picasa 3 and even better you can do **several photos at once.** (P.S. You can also just change the date taken properties of the file once it is on your local drive but you can only do one photo at a time.)

1. Either download the photo or photos from google photo or better yet find the original photo or photos on your local drive.
2. If you have several pictures you want to add or change the date taken that are not in the same folder together, put all those pics into a new folder.
3. Open any of the images using Picasa Viewer and choose "edit in Picasa" or find the folder containing the pictures you would like to change with in Picasa 3.
4. Highlight the photos you would like to change the date taken properties of (by left clicking and dragging).
5. Go to the top and open "tools" from the menu and then click "adjust date and time..." about half way down the drop down box.
6. The "Adjust Photo Date" Box will open and it will tell you how many photos you are changing if more than one. You can probably figure it out from here.
7. After you have made your changes, upload these photos up to Google Photo and delete the photo(s) still on google photo with the wrong date/no date.

Done and done.

As far as I have found, Google Photo only merges duplicates if every property of the duplicate photos are exactly the same (including file name, size of file, date taken, and so on.)

Comment: made my day, I have a go pro with tons of photos

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you didn't set up a Google Photos account.

Google Photos is a tool you can use for managing your photo collection.  Other tools that work on the same photo collection are Google+ Photos, and Picasa Web Albums.    One collection.  Several ways to access it.

Now - it doesn't look like Google Photos offers a way to change the date  associated with a photo (yet).

Picasa web albums does let you change the date of an album:

- Go to https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1
- Find the album that the offending photo(s) are in
- Click on the album
- The Actions drop down has an Album Properties function which lets you
  edit the date.

Changing this should allow you to see photos in the correct order in the Collections tab of Google Photos, even if not in the individual photos tab.

And as you've noted in the other answer, you can use Picasa's Edit in Google+ link to get to a screen where you can change the date of individual photos, which are what shows by default when you first enter Google Photos.

Comment: Did not help - see my answers update

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Google Plus account, you can access your photos through plus.google.com.  Clicking on a photo then gives you the option of changing its date.  (It's curious that Google Photos doesn't have this feature.)

Sorry - I know this solution won't work if you don't have a G+ account.

Answer (score -3):

I have an apple photos account and it lets you change the date.  After I set the correct date in Apple photos I export from apple and import into google (now with with the correct date.) Then delete the old Google photo.

Comment: He asked how to do it without having to delete the photos.